# Objective-C: help me convert a timestamp to a formatted date/time

Tags: objective-c, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm really struggling to convert this timestamp to a nice formatted date string.

Here's the timestamp: "1316625985"

And here's the function I've made:

```
-(NSString*)timestamp2date:(NSString*)timestamp{
    NSString * timeStampString =timestamp;
    //[timeStampString stringByAppendingString:@"000"];   //convert to ms
    NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString doubleValue];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
    NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];
    return [_formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Trouble is, it keeps returning dates in 1972! (31/7/72) This is wrong, since it's a September 2011 date...

Can anyone suggest any solution?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried working with NSCalendar and NSDateComponents to form your date object?  That's how I've ended up doing it in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check that the string (`timestampString`) and the double value (`_interval`) are the same, and that the `doubleValue` does really takes all the characters of your string into account?

Maybe the interpretation of the string into double crops the value?

---

Are you also sure that the timestamp you are interpretting is really a UNIX timestamp, meaning it counts the number of seconds elapsed since 01/01/1970 (and not days since 01/01/1970?… or not seconds but since another date?)

*(Maybe give an example of the value of the timestamp you are trying to interpret)*

Comment: He did give an example of the timestamp above.  I tried it and the string & double are the same so that's not it.

Answer (score 15):

Isn't epoch **seconds** since 1/1/1970?  are you sure that you didn't leave the millisecond line in?

When I ran you're logic (without your line append 000 for ms), it worked.  Here's what I did:

```
    NSString * timeStampString = @"1316641549";
    NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString doubleValue];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

It outputted:

2011-09-21 17:46:14.384 Craplet[13218:707] **2011-09-21 21:45:49 +0000**

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm falling asleep here. I'll have to look at it in the morning. I'll have happy dreams now!

Comment: Cool - log out the date like I'm doing above just to make sure you're not hitting some formatting issue ...

Answer (score 5):

Just divide your [timeStampString doubleValue] by a thousand like:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[timeStampString doubleValue]/1000.0];
NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];
return [_formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

or try [timeStampString longLongValue]/1000.0 instead

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `[timeStampString doubleValue]` directly into `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` instead of converting it into an `NSTimeInterval`.

Also, try adding some NSLog statements to see what your values are at various points, that should help track down where the difference is.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

While using NSInterval to get the interval, make sure the timestamp is in seconds and not milliseconds. If it is in milliseconds, just divide the NSInterval value by 1000 and then try formatting.